# Why does UserManager.FindById() return null if I do not relog?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

I'm trying to find the user associated with the currently logged on user:

```
public ActionResult Root(string path)
{
    var id = User.Identity.GetUserId(); //This works
    var currentUser = manager.FindById(id); //This returns null

    return View(db.Folders.ToList()
        .Where(folder => folder.User.Id == currentUser.Id)
        .Where(folder => folder.Path == path));
}
```

This only works if I do not use the indicated part in my seed method. If I do execute this part, manager.FindById() returns null.

```
    protected override void Seed(ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        if (context == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("context", "Context must not be null.");
        }

        const string UserName = "admin@tad.com";
        const string RoleName = "Admin";

        var userRole = new IdentityRole { Name = RoleName, Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() };
        context.Roles.Add(userRole);

        var hasher = new PasswordHasher();

        var user = new ApplicationUser
        {
            UserName = UserName,
            PasswordHash = hasher.HashPassword("123456"),
            Email = "admin@tad.com",
            EmailConfirmed = true,
            SecurityStamp = Guid.NewGuid().ToString()
        };

        user.Roles.Add(new IdentityUserRole { RoleId = userRole.Id, UserId = user.Id });

        context.Users.Add(user);

        //If I leave this part out, there are no issues.
        new List<Folder>
        { 
            new Folder{Name = "Test", Path = "", User = user},
            new Folder{Name = "Bla", Path = "Test", User = user},
            new Folder{Name = "Lala", Path = "Test/Bla", User = user}
        }.ForEach(f => context.Folders.Add(f));

        context.SaveChanges();

        base.Seed(context);
    }
```

**EDIT: Starting to narrow it down. If I relog my user, everything works just fine.** The active user during testing remains logged in from the previous debugging session.

Comment: What is the value of `id` in `var id = User.Identity.GetUserId();`? does user with this ID exists in your database? on the side note do you have `context.SaveChanges()` in your `Seed` method?

Comment: @trailmax `id` is the user's Guid, and it exists in the database. `context.SaveChanges()` does not seem to help. I'll post my entire `Seed()` method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see the problem:

> The active user during testing remains logged in from the previous debugging session.

Authentication cookie contains the Guid for userId from the previous session. And if you re-create users every time, guid for userId is getting changed in the database and does not match for whatever Id is stored in the cookie. So either don't re-create users on every debug session, or kill your cookies on every debug.

Comment: Makes sense. I reasoned it was the same account, because it wasn't logging me out automatically.

Comment: Yeah, this is one of the things you get with Identity, when it does not re-validate your cookie on every request. But you can make it do so if you like.